# Duplicate process in cron job using Whenever gem for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, cron

Using Rails 3.2.21, whenever gem. This is the list of my crontab:

`Begin Whenever generated tasks for: abc
0 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/deployer/abc/releases/20141201171336 && 
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake backup:perform --silent'`

Here's the output when the scheduled job is run:

`deployer@localhost:~$ ps aux | grep rake
deployer 25593  0.0  0.0   4448   764 ?        Ss   12:00   0:00 /bin/sh -c /bin/bash -l -c 
'cd /home/deployer/abc/releases/20141201171336 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake 
backup:perform --silent'
deployer 25594  0.0  0.1  12436  3040 ?        S    12:00   0:00 /bin/bash -l -c cd 
/home/deployer/abc/releases/20141201171336 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake 
backup:perform --silent
deployer 25631 69.2  4.4 409680 90072 ?        Sl   12:00   0:06 ruby /home/deployer/abc/
shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake backup:perform --silent
deployer 25704  0.0  0.0  11720  2012 pts/0    S+   12:00   0:00 grep --color=auto rake`

Notice the the top 2 processes are actually similar processes. Are they running 2 same jobs concurrently? How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> deployer 25593  0.0  0.0   4448   764 ?        Ss   12:00   0:00 /bin/sh -c /bin/bash …
> deployer 25594  0.0  0.1  12436  3040 ?        S    12:00   0:00 /bin/bash …
> ```
>
> Notice the the top 2 processes are actually similar processes. Are they running 2 same jobs concurrently?

No, they aren't. The first is a `/bin/sh` that started the second, the *crontab* command `/bin/bash …`. Most probably `/bin/sh` is just waiting for termination of `/bin/bash` and not running again before `/bin/bash …` has finished execution; you can verify this with e. g. `strace -p 25593`.

Answer (score -2):

Check your scheduled.rb for a duplicate entry, if you find then remove and deploy.
If there is no duplicate entry in scheduled.rb then you need to remove/comment it from cron tab.
To delete or comment jobs in cron take a look at https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/scripts-and-programming-languages-c85099/cron-jobs-c37727/delete-a-cron-job-a757264.html OR http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/dv/hats/cats/stations/qnxman/crontab.html

Comment: The actual cause might be not providing the `whenever_identifier` or `application` setting in deploy.rb

Comment: I had this problem. Then i found out, that in deploy.rb file this 'whenever' action was called twice.